# How to use `.` while forming a query for mongo

Tags: mongodb, morphia

Apologies if this question has been asked before.

```
Query<Comment> q = createQuery();
        q.and(q.criteria("parent.$id").in(parentObjectIds), q.criteria("status")
                .equal(status.name()));

throws :  Can not use dot-notation past 'parent' could not be found in 'entity.Comment' while validating - parent.$id
```

while this works fine.

```
db.getCollection('Comment').find({"parent.$id": {$in: [ObjectId("54c6b3e7e4b0df51ab756c51"),ObjectId("54dba376e4b026c6809c8f91") ]}})
```

I am guessing the query generated by Morphia should be similar to this query.

Here is the Comment Document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5511b0f2e4b0d7b61ff9764a"),
"entity" : {
    "$ref" : "Entity",
    "$id" : ObjectId("54c6b35fe4b0df51ab756c4f")
},
"content" : "Some Test Content",
"parent" : {
    "$ref" : "Comment",
    "$id" : ObjectId("54c6b3e7e4b0df51ab756c51")
},
"childCount" : 0,
"score" : 0
```

}

Here is the comment class for reference which is being used in the Query.

```
public class Comment extends Stats{

@Reference(lazy=true)
private EngEntity entity;   
private String content;
private Status status;
private boolean canReply;
@Reference
private Comment parent;
private int score;


public boolean isCanReply() {
    return canReply;
}

public Comment setCanReply(boolean canReply) {
    this.canReply = canReply;
    return this;
}

public Entity getEntity() {
    return entity;
}

public Comment setEntity(Entity entity) {
    this.entity = entity;
    return this;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public Comment setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
    return this;
}

public Status getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public Comment setStatus(Status status) {
    this.status = status;
    return this;
}

public Comment getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public Comment setParent(Comment parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    return this;
}


public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public Comment setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
    return this;
}
```

}

Comment: Could we have an example of a Comment document so we can understand the shape ?

Comment: @NicCottrell added.

Answer (score 1):

`DBRef` can be referenced by `name`.

```
Query<Comment> q = datastore.createQuery(Comment.class);
Comment comment1 = new Comment();
comment1.setId(new ObjectId("54c6b3e7e4b0df51ab756d51"));
Comment comment2 = new Comment();
comment2.setId(new ObjectId("54dba376e4b026c6809c8f91"));
q.criteria("parent").in(Arrays.asList(comment1,comment2));
List<Comment> comments = q.asList();
```

Without Validation:

`DBRef` can be referenced by `$id`.

```
Query<Comment> q = datastore.createQuery(Comment.class).disableValidation().field("parent.$id").hasAny‌​Of(parentObjectIds);
List<Comment> comments = q.asList();
```

Comment: Thanks, What does `disableValidation ()` do? It stopped the exception but not getting anything in result. Have I translated the query correctly or I missed something?

Comment: @user1324887 You are welcome . What is the query you are transforming ? Disable validation will skip checking the fields you used in query against the fields define in class. Do you mean to use $ in the query ? And add a sample doc from comment collection

Comment: 1. I have all these fields defined in the `Comment` class. Why I need to add `disableValidation() `? 2. translating `db.getCollection('Comment').find({"parent.$id": $ in [ObjectId("54c6b3e7e4b0df51ab756c51”),ObjectId("54dba376e4b026c6809c8f91”) ]})` query in to Morphia query

Comment: How did you define `$id` in `comment` class ? Is `$id` a name of field ? How is it related to `parent` ?

Comment: added the comment Document with the question. `parent` is a object reference and `$id` is its `ObjectId`

Comment: Updated. Can you give it a try ?

Comment: That doesnt seem to work. It results in this query: which returns nothing. `{ "$and" : [ { "parent" : { "$in" : [ { "$oid" : "54dba371e4b026c6809c8f90"} , { "$oid" : "54dba080e4b026c6809c8f74"} , { "$oid" : "54dba081e4b026c6809c8f75"} , { "$oid" : "55271e5be4b00a12957317d3"} , { "$oid" : "54dba376e4b026c6809c8f91"}]}} , { "status" : "ACTIVE"}]}`

Comment: What version of morphia are you using ? And can you please add the comment class ? You will need to add @Reference annotation on the parent field

Comment: I tried, that didn't work either. I have added the `class`. Morphia version is 0.111.

Comment: Not sure if this a problem. Can you generate regular setters ? Right now it looks like all setters retuning comment class. It works for with regular set up.

Comment: I changed the comment class and tried both the versions, not working.

Comment: I changed the query to `Query<Comment> q = createQuery().disableValidation().field("parent.$id").hasAnyOf(parentObjectIds).field("status").equal(status.name());` This one works.

Comment: Glad it worked. Added code that worked for me without disabling validation and also included your solution in the answer.